# php and mySQL how to get highest value in a varchar column

Tags: php, sql

In a case where I have a column that needs to be unique eg. product:eggs, tomatoes, pepper, pepper1, pepper2
and before i insert another pepper i need to check the last integer, and add 1 to it, so the next pepper would be 'pepper3'
How would i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The easy way is to have two columns: the first for the label and the second for the id.
It's never good to mix up various information in the same column.

Then you could do something like :

```
SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM ... WHERE label = "pepper"
```

and

```
SELECT CONCAT(label,product_id) FROM ... WHERE id = ...
```

Returns what you want.

Comment: +1 And use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on the composite primary key.

Comment: +1 : mentioning that compounding multiple items of information into a single field is a Bad Idea (tm).  Having two fields makes each field easy to use, and it's always easy to concatenate them for use on screen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(product_name, 6) AS product_name_plain,
    CAST(RIGHT(product_name, 6) AS UNSIGNED) AS product_number
  FROM product_table
  WHERE product_name_plain = "pepper"
  ORDER BY product_number DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

- The `SELECT` breaks apart product names into the plain name ("pepper"), and an unsigned integer version of the product number (3).
- The `WHERE` clause identifies the peppers.
- The `ORDER BY` will sort them (which should result in the last pepper being the first result)
- The `LIMIT` will only fetch the one result.
- Note that "6" and "pepper" are hard-coded in this query, your code would have to put them in. 6 is the length of "pepper."

Comment: Wouldn't this select `peppercorn` and `peppermint`? What about incrementing the number?

Comment: @Wesley Good point. I reorganized the query to account for this, and to be better about sorting. Of course nax's answer is more "proper," but there are plenty of times when we can't reorganize the schema to make something more proper. :)